# Cache files using Grunt task.

Tags: caching, gruntjs

I encountered the following code when reading a project's `gruntfile.js` , as the comment indicates, the code is used for `Renames files for browser caching purposes`, but how? What will be the new names for those files?

```
    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/assets/js/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/assets/css/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using `grunt-rev` based upon the `Gruntfile.js` snippet.

As the [project GitHub page](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) describes, the rev task will change file names so that browsers are forced to download fresh copies (as opposed to use stale cached copies).

In the [project docs on 'Basic Asset Revving'](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev#basic-asset-revving), you'll see that the task simply renames the file to an eight character hash.  In the docs, they give the example of `js/9becff3a.app.js`.

Thus, each time you run a grunt task that includes the revving, a new set of 'cache-busting' file names will be generated using the 8-character hashed rename.

Comment: Thanks! So for example, all js files in `<%= config.dist %>/assets/js/{,*/}` will be replaced with the renamed files?

Comment: Yeah, the files covered by the `src` globs/patterns will get replaced.  Note that if you are hard-coding file names that will get revved, you'll run into problems post-rev.  This is why the rev package is used by things like `usemin` that already do some other file naming tasks and can integrate the revving.

Comment: It's not random (it's a hash based on the file contents) and will only be different if the file changes.

Comment: @steveax - you are right.  sloppy on my part, rushing through an answer.  Updating the answer now to recognize this.

Comment: How can I update my index.html with the busted file names automatically? Is there any tool/task that can do so after running the rev ?